# Se sobreescribe Scope al tener varias instancias del mismo componente angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Mi duda es que tengo un componente en angularjs que quiero utilizar varias veces en una misma página pasando distintos parámetros. Este componente tiene dentro un multiselect (http://dotansimha.github.io/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/docs/#/main). Así tengo definido mi componente:

```
angular.module('app')
    .component('filtros', {
        templateUrl: './filtros.html',
        bindings: {
        },
        controller: ['$scope', '$http', '$translate', filtrosController]
    });

function filtrosController($scope, $http, $translate) {
    $scope.multiselectConfig = {
        model: [],
        data: [],
        settings: { checkBoxes: true },
        text: {
            checkAll: $translate.instant('checkAll'),
            uncheckAll: $translate.instant('uncheckAll'),
            buttonDefaultText: $translate.instant('buttonDefaultText'),
            dynamicButtonTextSuffix: $translate.instant('dynamicButtonTextSuffix')
        }
    };
      $scope.config.filtro = {
        tipo: {
            titulo: "Tipo",
            apiUrl: api.tipo,
            multiselect: {
                config: $scope.multiselectConfig
            }
        },
        estado: {
            titulo: "Estado",
            apiUrl: api.estado,
            multiselect: {
                config: $scope.multiselectConfig
            }
        }
    };


angular.module('app')
    .component('filtroSimple', {
        templateUrl: './filtroSimple.html',
        bindings: {
            config: '<'
        },
        controllerAs: '$ctrl',
        controller: ['$scope', '$http', '$translate', filtroSimpleController]
    });

function filtroSimpleController($scope, $http, $translate) {
    var $ctrl = this.config;
    $ctrl.fn = {
        cargarFiltro: cargarFiltro
    };

    $ctrl.fn.cargarFiltro();

    function cargarFiltro() {
        $http.get($ctrl.apiUrl)
            .then(function (response) {
                if (response.data) {
                    $ctrl.multiselect.config.data = response.data;
                }
            });
    }
}

<filtro-simple config="config.filtro.tipo"></filtro-simple>
<filtro-simple config="config.filtro.estado"></filtro-simple>
```

Al final, el resultado es que ambos componentes tienen los datos del último componente. Es decir, en el primero se cargaron los estados, y en el segundo también se cargaron los estados (aunque viendo la ejecución paso a paso, el primero recibe bien los datos de tipo).

¿Por qué se sobrescriben los valores?

EDIT: Hice un test en Plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/QSrlr4nHR4yh2cmEqR2y?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Analizando un poco el problema que tienes, encontré una solución que puede ayudarte a resolver tu situación, el problema que tienes es que estas llamando la variable `$scope.multiselectConfig` en cada objeto del `$scope.config.filtro` es decir en el `multiselect` de `tipo:` y `estado:` y pues claro te va tomar el mismo resultado para ambos `multiselect`, A continuación te dejo una solución oportuna:

```
$scope.multiselectConfigType = {
    model: [],
    data: [],
    settings: { checkBoxes: true },
    text: {
        checkAll: $translate.instant('checkAll'),
        uncheckAll: $translate.instant('uncheckAll'),
        buttonDefaultText: $translate.instant('buttonDefaultText'),
        dynamicButtonTextSuffix: $translate.instant('dynamicButtonTextSuffix')
    }
};
$scope.multiselectConfigState = {
    model: [],
    data: [],
    settings: { checkBoxes: true },
    text: {
        checkAll: $translate.instant('checkAll'),
        uncheckAll: $translate.instant('uncheckAll'),
        buttonDefaultText: $translate.instant('buttonDefaultText'),
        dynamicButtonTextSuffix: $translate.instant('dynamicButtonTextSuffix')
    }
};
  $scope.config.filtro = {
    tipo: {
        titulo: "Tipo",
        apiUrl: api.tipo,
        multiselect: {
            config: $scope.multiselectConfigType 
        }
    },
    estado: {
        titulo: "Estado",
        apiUrl: api.estado,
        multiselect: {
            config: $scope.multiselectConfigState
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Gracias! funciona correctamente.  Pero el caso es que antes de obtener tu respuesta estuve probando con otro componente (http://isteven.github.io/angular-multi-select/#/main) y con la misma configuración sí me muestra bien la información... (¿?)